# Dependency injection Email Manager constructor call

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor, dependency-injection, email

This one is a follow up question to [Dependency Injection using Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998282/dependency-injection-using-unity-in-asp-net/29999726#29999726)

So , as a set up I have a `CustomConfiguration.cs` file which is supposed to populate from a config section in my `web.config` file

This is the signature for the file

```
public class CustomConfiguration : ICustomProcessorConfig, IEmailConfig, IReportConfig
    {
        #region Properties

        private CustomProcessorConfig ConfigSection { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors (1)

        public CustomConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customConfiguration") as ConfigSection;
        }

        #endregion Constructors 

        #region ICustomConfiguration Members

        public string Text { get { return ConfigSection.Text; } }

        public string Subject { get { return ConfigSection.Subject; } }

        public string SmtpHost { get { return ConfigSection.EmailSettings.SmtpHost; } }

        public int SmtpPort { get { return ConfigSection.EmailSettings.SmtpPort; } }
```

These are the 3 files I have for Email Generation :

```
 public interface IEmailManager
    {

        void SendEmail(string toAddress, string fromAddress, string subject, string body, bool htmlBody);

}

 public interface IEmailConfig
    {
        string SmtpHost { get;  }

        int SmtpPort { get;  }
   }
```

And Finally I have the Email Manager which inherits the IEmailManager interface

```
public class EmailManager: IEmailManager
    {

        #region Constructors (1)

        public EmailManager(IEmailConfiguration configuration)
        {
            CurrentSmtpClient = new SmtpClient
                                    {
                                        Host = configuration.SmtpHost,
                                        Port = configuration.SmtpPort,
                                        Credentials =
                                            new NetworkCredential(configuration.UserName, configuration.Password)
                                    };
        }

        #endregion Constructors 

// send Mail is also implemented
}
```

Coming back to the previous question I have my set up like :

```
Container = new UnityContainer();
  Container.RegisterType<ICustomConfiguration,CustomConfiguration>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); 

                Container.RegisterType<IEmailManager, EmailManager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

                Container.RegisterType<IReportGenerator, ReportGenerator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

Configuration = Container.Resolve<ICustomConfiguration>(); 
                Emailer = Container.Resolve<IEmailManager>(); 
                ReportGenerator = Container.Resolve<IReportGenerator>();
```

I'm getting a `ResolutionFailedException`saying The parameter configuration could not be resolved when attempting to call constructor for `EmailManager`.

I had a different DI setup and I would need the configuration information from `IEmailConfig` still. Is there a way of going past this ? I need the config information to proceed with sending the email as you can guess with my setup.

Am I binding different repo to my Container ? Or how should I change my EmailManager code ?

Comment: Is the implementation of IEmailConfiguration in another assembly? If not, why don't you register it in the container?

Comment: sorry about the confusion . It's not a different file , it's the IEmailConfig interface file @nimeshjm

Comment: Ok, so you need to register the IEmailConfig interface with the CustomConfiguration  class in the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the IEmailConfig interface with the CustomConfiguration class in the container.

```
  Container.RegisterType<IEmailConfig , CustomConfiguration >(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: My CustomConfiguration class is inheriting all my 3 IConfig files ( as in ICustomProcessorConfig ,  IEmailConfig , IReportConfig ) . Why do I need to register the 3 interfaces then ? Or do I need to register all of them ?

Comment: IEmailConfiguration or IEmailConfig

Comment: Your EmailManager class is being injected with an object that implements IEmailConfiguration. Your container is performing this injection. You need to tell your container how to resolve IEmailConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

IEmailConfiguration missing mapping in the unity container. Need to add the concrete class that maps this interface

Comment: My CustomConfiguration class is inheriting all my 3 IConfig files ( as in ICustomProcessorConfig ,  IEmailConfig , IReportConfig ) . Why do I need to register the 3 interfaces then ? Or do I need to register all of them ?